# drupal how to change the login block button value

Tags: php, drupal, authentication, drupal-blocks

I want to change the text that currently says "log in" on my drupal site.

It is built on drupal 7 on a sub theme of omega. I have made a hook to the login block by following some instructions found here: http://drupal.org/node/1167712, which basically adds some code into the themes template.php and then making a tpl.php in the templates folder in the theme.

I can get it to put more thing into the login block by this method so i know that its hooking to it properly, just dont know how to change the "value" of the "log in" button.

Comment: I also tied this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32570/drupal-7-change-user-login-block-link-text but with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out the [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module. Good for making a few changes here and there.

Comment: cheers for that! worked a treat and no code editing required :)

Answer (score 1):

In your template.php , add a [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).

```
function yourthemenamehere_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  //print_r($form) // This will display form elements.
  if($form_id == "user_login") {
      $form['actions']['submit']['#value']= "YOUR TEXT HERE";
  }
}
```

Comment: small addition: the form id for the login block is user_login_block

Answer (score 0):

Though not exactly what you asked. You might find the following link helpful -
[Add Dyanmic login logut link to primary menu](http://www.zyxware.com/articles/2044/drupal-tips-how-to-add-dynamic-login-logout-link-to-your-primary-menu). It should give you a starting point.